# How to cite full author name using Jabref in latex?

Tags: latex, biblatex

Hi. I am using JabRef for citation and Harvard style. I want cite the full author name in some cases. How do I do this with JabRef?

For example:

> Many people defined frogs as animals (John Frank, 2000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply type `{John Frank}` in the **author** field in JabRef.

Answer (score 0):

HI

I could solve this problem in this way;
John-Frank,
This brought all the name in front of the publication year.

Cheers!!